# How to clea Authentication Cache from browser to custom signout sharepoint page completly

Tags: authentication, logging, site

This code I have using to clear the cache so that it has automatically sign-out from SharePoint site and it has to prompt the authentication dialog to login again.

```
function _spBodyOnLoad() {
        document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
    }
```

This code I am in custom sign out page to clear Authentication cache, But the problem is that, it clears all the cache so if user browsing two different site in same browser with different tab it also automatically got sign out. Any idea to resolve the issue?